# Finding the flux integral?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

Evaluate the flux integral $FdS$ 
where $F=\langle5y,2z,3x\rangle$  and $S$ is the part of the plane $6x+2y+z=12$ in the first octant oriented upward.

This is how I solved it but the answer is incorrect so I just was hoping someone could look at my work and tell me where I'm going wrong.

$\langle5,2,3\rangle \cdot \langle6,2,1\rangle = 37$

$6x+2y=12$ I solved for $y$. So $y=6-3x$

So I took the integral of $37dydx$ where $y$ goes from $0$ to $6-3x$ and $x$ goes from $0$ to $2$. My final answer was $222$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take care:
$$z=12-6x-2y$$
and
$$\iint \limits_D \vec {F} \cdot \langle -\frac{\partial z}{\partial x},-\frac{\partial z}{\partial y},1\rangle \, \mathrm{d}y\, \mathrm{d}x $$
$$= \iint \limits_D \langle5y,2z,3x\rangle \cdot \langle6,2,1\rangle \, \mathrm{d}y\, \mathrm{d}x =\iint \limits_D (30y+4z+3x) \, \mathrm{d}y\, \mathrm{d}x = $$
$$=\iint \limits_D (48+22y-21x) \, \mathrm{d}y\, \mathrm{d}x =$$
$$=\int_0^2 (48(6-3x)+11(6-3x)^2-21x(6-3x)) dx=$$
$$=\int_0^2 (684 -666x+162x^2) dx= 468$$

Comment: Are the bounds I have okay?

Comment: @Ayoshna It seems to be okay.

Comment: did u get 45pi?

Comment: I didn't calculate. But why with $\pi$?

Comment: I don't know... I evaluated it 3 times and got three different answers. I got -54 and -324

Comment: Have you ended up with this: $\int_0^2 (48(6-3x)+11(6-3x)^2-21x(6-3x)) dx$?

Comment: Yes and then I solved all that got to get -36x^2 + 129x-108. I then integrated this from 0 to 2